# Overriding In-line styles (CSS, CSS3)

Tags: css, content-management-system, overriding, restriction

I hope this is not a stupid question. I have been working with a management system and have no direct access to the HTML which is quite interesting. I do however have access to one CSS file and have been working with this. So far things have been going well although with certain in-line elements I am finding it hard to edit them here is an example (trying to remove a border):

```
.inner-container {
border: 1px solid #DDD;
background-color: #FFF;
color: #333333;
padding: 20px 15px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
.inner-container {
border: none!important;
}
```

& a more complex version

```
.inner-container[style^="border: 1px solid #DDD"] {
border: none !important;
background-color: #FFF;
color: #333333;
padding: 20px 15px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

I understand some have said that using !important to override a CSS element is bad practice and I have tried with and without. Does anyone have any suggestions, please let me know?

EDIT**

```
<div class="inner-container public-catalog-layout">
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Open DevTools (F12), inspect your element, right click it in DevTools and select `Break on...` -> `Attributes modifications`. If those inline-styles are added through JS, that should take you to the exact line of code that adds the border, you can change it there. If the inline-style is included in the markup, then you have two options: use JS to override the styles (preferably), or just stick to !important.

Comment: could you post the html code for that tag ?

Comment: @Saa_keetin EDIT**

Comment: So in my codepen link : http://codepen.io/saa93/pen/xRbWEa i have added in line style, removed it through css and also added one through jquery. in css adding border:none !important seem to work. in your case if it isnt working you might have to inspect the element in the browse to exactly know whats going on. may be you can post what you find here. It would help in providing you with a solution. Also to add please check public-catalog-layout doesnt have css that could be effecting the border.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz I have no access to JS files or the index/HTML files, I have access to one CSS file which is why this issue is quite interesting. I have to manipulate the main code using one CSS file. However to see if this is possible I have used the *{border:none!important} within this file and it is.

Comment: @Saa_keetin Yes I have tried this modifying the code slightly adding white where you have stated pink still with no luck. From what I can see this element is not only being controlled by another CSS file (public.css; the file which I have access to is common.css) it also has some in-line CSS rules it follows. I have used *{border:none!important} with success however I do not want to remove every border from this system.

Comment: If some thing else is taking precendece of your css and you dont have access to the css file it kinda makes things hard. Give this a try
.container.public-catalog-layout{
  border-color:transparent !important;
}'

Comment: @Saa_keetin Yes this is not working either. I have been thinking about other ways which I can manipulate/override this maybe using the asterisk with the addition of a selector maybe

Comment: Maybe `div{border:none;}` or if `.inner-container` is wrapped in a parent you could try `.parentName div{border:none;}` where `.parentName` is the class name of the wrapper assuming there is one.

Comment: @Todd the div{border:none;} has successfully remove the border for this specific element, it has however remove the borders for all HTML div tags I would have to go through the entire HTML doc overriding using !important the other elements. I can explore this and keep everyone updated. It is similar to using the asterisks however it does not remove the borders of  every element.

Comment: Does `.inner-container` have an *.outer-container* of any kind? If it does then try `.outer-container div{border:none;}`

Comment: @Todd The .outer-container follows a separate stylesheet which I cannot edit explicitly it relies on me having to override a whole element i.e. the div. I would much prefer encapsulating this main issue.

Comment: The reason that using `div{border:none;}` overrides the styling set with *.inner-container* without needing *!important* is due to specificity, *div* is more specific so overrides styling set with *.inner-container*. As you said using `div{border:none;}` alone overrides every *div* which is not what you want. You can overcome this using the class or id name of its wrapper to override this *div* alone. I am not saying that you need to use another stylesheet. `wrapper div{boarder:none;}` would override only the *div* boarder in the wrapper of that class or id name.